# CSS - The property initial-letter don't work in any browser

Tags: css

I want the first letter of my paragraph to be larger than the rest so that it occupies the height of three lines in the paragraph. I have tried to use the "initial-letter" in my CSS code and it doesn't work in any browser: Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome or Safari.

I know this question has been asked before and I know that a solution is to use the property "float:left" for "first-letter". After I can apply the property "margin" and ready....ok ...ok ...ok

But I can't believe that the property "initial-letter" doesn't work right. My code is plain:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
section{background-color:blue;
width:600px;
margin:auto;}

p::first-letter{
initial-letter:3;}

p{color:white;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Entendiendo la propiedad "first-letter" de CSS</h1>
</header>
<section>
<p>Este texto esta pensado para ver el pseudoelemento ::first-letter que permite en CSS
modificar las caracteristicas de la primera letra de un parrafo (normalmente se modifica 
                el tamano).</p> 
</section>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: yes only safari support it: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-letter (with prefix)

Comment: You wanted this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Answer (score 4):

You could `float: left` a [`::first-letter` pseudo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

```css
p.first-letter::first-letter {
  float:left;
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  color: red;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: -0.1em;
}
```

```html
<p class="first-letter">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est. Este texto esta pensado para ver el pseudoelemento ::first-letter que permite en CSS modificar las caracteristicas de la primera letra de un parrafo (normalmente se modifica el tamano).</p>
```

[Initial letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial-letter) is only supported in Safari